# Every year invoice number reset using php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I need to prepare invoice using php mysql, i have prepared and my problem is every year invoice number reset to first.

ex: 2013 - 1, 2013 - 2, 2013 -3. 2014-1, 2014-2, 2014-3.

My table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `gen` (
`id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`invno` int(11),
`prefix` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
`year` year(4) DEFAULT NULL,
`created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (`invno`,`year`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Code is

```
$year = date("Y", time());

$sql = "SELECT year FROM gen where year = '$year' ";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);
$inv = '0';

if ($count == 0) {
    $inv = '0';
} else {
    $list = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $inv = $list['invno'];
}

if ($inv == '0') {
    $inv = '1';
} else {
    $inv++;
}

echo $inv;
```

it is showing '1' when i execute, there are more invoices in table. i have set year in separate field. i think sql query check year in table if no rows found in that year invoice number should be set as 1, other wise increment previous number.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: `if($inv == '0'){$inv = '1';}else{$inv++;}` is equivalent to `$inv++`

Comment: if empty rows found  i have set $inv = 0, then next condition  if $inv = 0, then $inv = 1 i have set. other wise previous $inv++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you forgot to initialize `$inv`

Try

```
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);
$inv = '0';
if($count == '0')
{
$inv = '0';
.....
```

also you are not selecting `invno` in your query

```
$sql="SELECT year FROM gen where year = '$year' ";
$inv = $list['invno'];


$sql="SELECT max(invno) FROM gen where year = '$year' ";// may be this is what you want
```

Answer (score 0):

hey first the number is a string. remove the '' and put numbers only.  if($count == 0)

Answer (score 0):

This would help you.

````
//gets the maximum number of till the date
$result=$db->query("SELECT max(date),max(billno) FROM invoice;");
  $billno = $result->fetch_row()[1];
  $billno+=1;
  //if the the new year begans the it will reset bill number to 1
  if (date("m")==1 && date("d")==1) {
    $billno=1;  
    }
    echo $billno;```
````